# How to make UICollectionView custom layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to make such as custom CollectionView layout.
[image]

Each cell's location will be random but cells should not be overlapping each other. 
I have tried [DSCircularCollectionView](https://github.com/DoddaSrinivasan/DSCircularCollectionView) but I want cell position randomly without overlapping. How can I make it with Objective-c?

Comment: Do you really need it to be a `UICollectionView`? Or could you simply use a "randomize location" function to position the views?

Comment: Yes it should be UICollectionView, because each item is UICollectionViewCell

Comment: You have made each item a `UICollectionViewCell` because you are trying to use a `UICollectionView`. What benefits of a collection view are you expecting to get, that you could not get without it?

Comment: I am using some delegate methods such as didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @DonMag, the right approach is using the collection-view here.

Comment: @ÜnalÖztürk, there is no such thing _"no overlap"_, so the hardest thing is that creating the custom layout; the locations of the cells are something what you need to calculate explicitly based on the shape and size of the cells (incl. the name's label), not to overlap – but that is too broad, there could be many possible solution here, but starting with basic geometry could help on you.

Comment: @holex - *"the right approach is using the collection-view"* **and** *"there could be many possible solution here"*? There are times when it is valuable to re-think an approach. If I said "I want a UITableView to look like a grid" you would probably tell me to think about using a collection view, yes? So, I was simply suggesting that *maybe* using custom views as subviews instead of Cells and Collection Views could be a viable alternative. As in: *"there could be many possible solution here"*

Comment: @DonMag, using collection-view for the task is the obvious choice here but the actual custom layout (and the calculation in the custom layout) can be handled on various ways, there're more than one way to calculate the places of the items; of course it can be implemented without collection-views, but why would anyone make it harder than it's actually, your solution sounds easier in theory but more complex in practice; you'd start working out your idea but you'll find yourself in a situation when you want go back to collection-views (where it should've been started at). that is such simple.

Comment: @holex - cool.. I'd love to hear your suggestions to the OP on how to accomplish his task, other than "collection-view is the right approach" and "there could be many possible solution (to calculating the layout)".

Comment: @ÜnalÖztürk - The first image you posted *has* overlap, but you said you don't want any overlap. So, can you show an image (just lay it out by hand) showing how you *want* it to look? Best if you show it with as many "cells" as you expect to have... it is very different to get 3 cells to look good, than it is to get 10 cells to look good.

Comment: @DonMag It will be 5 cells. Each image and text are represent one cell

Comment: @DonMag, the OP needs to implement a custom layout for the collection-view; there are about thousand examples on the net... and Apple also has a very educational sample code: https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2015/downloads/Advanced-Collection-View.zip, I am sure that is a quite detailed answer to your concerns here...? I am not going to do the math for the OP (or for you), that is something what you need to work out on your own, using your geometry skills (if there is any).